# Security Concerns on client side rendering for AWS Amplify Auth component

Tags: authentication, security, next.js, aws-amplify

I am building an application with AWS Cognito and Next.js. I am using Amplify's default authtication component below.

```
'use client'
Amplify.configure(config);

export function App({ signOut, user }: WithAuthenticatorProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

This component does not work without the 'use client' directive. I am curious from a security perspective if this is a concern and if there is any potentially sensitive details one could expose if this component is client side. Thanks!